# How do you replace LoggerSilence with ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I run `heroku run rake db:migrate` to run the migrations for a rails app on Heroku, I get the following deprecation warning. How is it fixed?

`` DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/application.rb:18) ``

I also get the same warning when I then run: `heroku run rake db:seed` and again when I run `heroku run rake db:examples`

One point of confusion I have is that I have `config/application.rb` but it is in the root directory of the project, not within the /app directory. Am I supposed to create another config file inside the `app` directory (and if so, what goes in that file?). Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, I tracked down the issue to a dependency of `rails_12factor`— [rails_stout_logging](https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging/blob/b21ed3a29748d2fe62ef1f4fe6bda34294a42dc9/lib/rails_stdout_logging/rails.rb#L3).

It's apparently [not recommended](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor#new-rails-5-apps) to use `rails_12factor` for apps that are created with [`rails` 5+](https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging/pull/33#issuecomment-536696969) and I was running a Rails 6 app.

Simply removing `rails12_factor` solved the issue for me.